# Including WHERE clause in Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

I have created a working dynamic pivot.

```
DECLARE 
@AttributeNames as NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE
@AssetGroup as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Water',
@AssetType as NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'Water Meters',
@RecStatus as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'I';



SET @AttributeNames = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(AttributeName) AS [text()]
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT G1_ATTRIBUTE_NAME as AttributeName 
        FROM dbo.GASSET_MASTER INNER JOIN
                      dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE ON dbo.GASSET_MASTER.SERV_PROV_CODE = dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.SERV_PROV_CODE AND 
                      dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_SEQ_NBR = dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.G1_ASSET_SEQ_NBR
    --WHERE     (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_GROUP = ''' + @AssetGroup + ''') AND (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_TYPE = ''' + @AssetType + ''')
    ) AS AttributeName

ORDER BY AttributeName

FOR XML PATH('')),
1,1, N'');



SET @SQL = N'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT     dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_ID, dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.G1_ASSET_SEQ_NBR, dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.G1_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, 
                      dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.G1_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_GROUP, dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_TYPE, 
                      dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_STATUS, dbo.GASSET_MASTER.REC_STATUS
        FROM         dbo.GASSET_MASTER LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE ON dbo.GASSET_MASTER.SERV_PROV_CODE = dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.SERV_PROV_CODE AND 
                      dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_SEQ_NBR = dbo.GASSET_ATTRIBUTE.G1_ASSET_SEQ_NBR
        WHERE     (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_GROUP = ''' + @AssetGroup + ''') AND (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_TYPE = ''' + @AssetType + ''') AND (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.REC_STATUS <> ''' + @RecStatus + ''')) as SState

PIVOT (
MAX(G1_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) 
FOR G1_ATTRIBUTE_NAME IN(' + @AttributeNames + N')) AS P;';


Print @SQL
```

This code results in what i believe to be a properly formatted pivot. But when I attempt to use the commented out `WHERE` clause when building the columns no records are returned and no errors are received.

```
--WHERE     (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_GROUP = ''' + @AssetGroup + ''') AND (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_TYPE = ''' + @AssetType + ''')
```

I have attempted to change the `WHERE` clause in a number of different ways with no success. Any ideas how I could do this differently?

Comment: So is it working or is it not working? Or, are you just looking for a better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the commented line to this one:

```
WHERE     (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_GROUP = @AssetGroup ) AND (dbo.GASSET_MASTER.G1_ASSET_TYPE = @AssetType )
```

Explanation: The first query is not a dynamic query, you do not need to embed `'`

Comment: Of course!!! Now that you have pointed this out it seems so obvious. I am embarrassed to say how long I struggled with that. The query is working perfectly. Your help is much appreciated. I do not yet have enough reputation on the site to vote you up. I apologize for that.